# How can I change style for before/after in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying implement breadcrumbs with triangles using before/after in the CSS, as shown in this tutorial:

http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Relevant snippets:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>

.breadcrumb li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 65px;
    background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

However, I'm using it as a directed flow, something like:

Main_Category >> Sub_Category >> Details

This flow starts with Main_Category highlighted and other 2 parts dark, and  there's a  underneath that you can select from. On select, Sub_Category becomes highlighted and another  pops up.

How can I change the before/after border colors if they're pseudo-elements?

So from the tutorial, I think can do this on the main part:

```
<li><a href="#" ng-style="background: {{color}}">Home</a></li>
```

But there's nowhere for me to set *ng-style* for before/after, and the triangle colors end up unchanged.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to use an angular directive to dynamically style the before/after pseudo-tags.

Instead of using ng-style, use ng-class to attach a class that will determine which before/after pseudo class to use.

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
     <li><a href="#" ng-class="someBooleanInScope? 'color-0' : 'color-1'">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in CSS:

```
.breadcrumb li a:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;           
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

.breadcrumb li a.color-0:after {
    background: black;
}

.breadcrumb li a.color-1:after {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, the only minor change was "background: black;" to "border-left-color: black;" Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers don't allow you to style elements based on controller variable values. This answer does!

Use a `@HostBinding` to defined CSS vars which you can then use in your .scss file, making it very easy to style `:before` and `:after` dynamically.

.ts:

```
size = 10
padding = 2

@HostBinding('attr.style')
public get cssVars() {
  return `
    --switch-size: ${this.size};
    --switch-padding: ${this.padding};
    --switch-size-inner: ${this.size - this.padding * 2};
  `;
}
```

.scss:

```
.my-class:before {
  height: calc(var(--switch-size) * 1px);
}
```

NB: Some people use DomSanitizer when using this approach but I didn't find it necessary (it worked without it) - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252610/1205871

Answer (score 0):

ng-class should work for what you are trying to do.

```
 <li><a href="#" ng-style="ng-class="{beforeCSS: amIBeforeElement()}"">Home</a></li>
```

rough code [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using ng-style in this instance you may find it easier to use ng-class and apply a different class depending, this will allow you to keep all your CSS in a single place rather than overriding within the HTML.

Simply change your code to:

```
<li><a href="#" ng-class="{ 'breadcrumb-color': subCategory }">Home</a></li>
```

Where subCategory should be a boolean, on click you set subCategory and then it will add breadcrumb-color as a class value, you should end up with something like this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="breadcrumb-color">Home</a></li>
```

Some sample css, now you can set the before and after as you please:

```
.breadcrumb-color li a {
    background: red;
}

.breadcrumb-color li a:after { 
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define your colors in CSS:

```
.breadcrumb li a.main-category {
    background: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
}

.breadcrumb li a.main-category:after {
    border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
}

.breadcrumb li a.sub-category {
    background: hsla(44, 75%, 45%, 1);
}

.breadcrumb li a.sub-category:after {
    border-left-color: hsla(44, 75%, 45%, 1);
}

/* ... and so on for other categories */
```

Then use ngClass:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#" ng-class="{'main-category': isMainCategoryActive(), 'sub-category': isSubCategoryActive()}">Home</a></li>
    <!-- ... other breadcrumbs -->
</ul>
```

Set the above function in your controller.

```
$scope.isMainCategoryActive = function() {
    // Your logic to determine if main category is active
    return true; // Or false
};

$scope.isSubCategoryActive = function() {
    // Your logic to determine if sub category is active
    return false; // Or true
};
```